# Defining and using Models in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have started with sequelize ORM. Writing some API routes to test my understanding.

I have my connection file like:

```
**config/database.js**
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = new Sequelize('dbname', 'postgres', 'root', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres' 
  });

  module.exports = db;
```

Then authenticating my db in `app.js`

```
//Test DB
 db.authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database Connected.')
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error: ' + err)
    })
```

I have my models created in separated folder called models
Users.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = require('../config/database')


const User = db.define('users',{
    username: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
})

module.exports = User;
```

and in controller i am trying to use sequelize function:

```
    const db = require('../../config/database');
    const User = require('../../models/Users')
    console.log(typeof User)
    exports.addUser = async(req, res) => {
const newUser = await User.create({ username: req.body.username})
                                    res.send('User Added.')
}
```

I get this error : UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Postman Request :

```
{
    "username" : "test",
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with your sequalize model, but with the data you are expecting in User.create() : `{ username: req.body.username}`. Make sure that  `username` is actually in the body of the request.

Comment: @orotype added the postman request am sending.